# Clearing every element of Arrays nested inside a Dictionary

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift, for-in-loop

Using a nested Array of Strings inside a Dictionary (with a string index), I'm trying to create a function which allows me to when called upon loop through every indices of my dictionary and replace it with an empty array. However, doing the code below returns the following error
`<swift-imported-modules>:1: missing submodule 'cocoa'<REPL>:16:29: error: could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments category[index] = []` and I can't figure out why

If i just print `index`, I get the category strings as expected, and if I enter them manually into the loop, it works, this only happens when `index` is substituted. Unwrapping won't help either.

```
class myClass {

    var category: Dictionary<String, Array<String>> = [
        "cat1" : [],
        "cat2" : [],
        "cat3" : []
    ]

    func eraseContent() {
        for index in category {
            category[index] = []
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried looking at the reference guide but didn't find a deleteAll command which was supported by Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be accessing `category.keys`, like this:

```
func eraseContent() {
        for index in category.keys {
            category[index] = []
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Methinks this is what you wanted.

```
class myClass {

var category: Dictionary<String, Array<String>> = [
    "cat1" : [],
    "cat2" : [],
    "cat3" : []
]
func eraseContent(){
    for index in category {
        category[index.0] = []
    }
}
```

}

Comment: there is no difference in your added `-> ()` with what the author had. A return value of void is implied

Comment: Oh sorry, that was left in my copy and paste (I like being explicit in my code)

Comment: thanks a lot this worked! had to choose between your answer vs Jack's, chose his because it allowed to have more complex arguments in the for loop without needing to add as many '.0' (wish I could select both)

Comment: you can also do `for (index, _) in category { category[index] = [] }` or if you'd like to use the value, `for (index, val) in category {...`